# How to get horizontally alligned answers in exercises environment

Tags: exam, exercises

The following MWE aligns answers vertically like:

```
1.     4.     7.     10.
2.     5.     8.     11.
3.     6.     9.
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}  
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\longestlabel}
\settowidth{\longestlabel}{\bfseries\sffamily vv}
\settasks{after-item-skip=3pt,%gap for next row
        before-skip=2pt,%gap from the text above    
        after-skip=0pt,%gap for next question
        label-width=20pt,%width from left
        item-indent=25pt,%indent from left
        label=$\EgyptianBlue\bm{(\alph*)}$,
        column-sep=0em, label-align=left}

\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{Exercise}{0}

\begin{Exercise}
   \Question
   \Question
   \Question
\end{Exercise}
    
\begin{Answer}
    \begin{multicols}{4}
        \Question $(a)$
        \Question $(a)$
        \Question $(a)$
        \Question $(a)$
        \EndCurrentQuestion
    \end{multicols}
\end{Answer}
\setboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}{false}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

But I want them to be horizontally aligned. I do not want to use the `tasks` package.